# getaddrinfo behavior during reconnect

Tags: python, linux, networking, getaddrinfo

I noticed some curious behavior with python's `socket.getaddrinfo()`.

If I am connected to wifi and call socket.getaddrinfo(), it works (of course it does!):

```
In [3]: socket.getaddrinfo('charlesleifer.com', 80)
Out[3]: 
[...]
```

If I disconnect, then I will receive an error:

```
In [4]: socket.getaddrinfo('charlesleifer.com', 80)
    ---------------------------------------------------------
    gaierror                                  Traceback (most
    <ipython-input-2-d333ec6c75af> in <module>()
    ----> 1 socket.getaddrinfo('charlesleifer.com', 80)
```

Finally, if I reconnect, it will work again.

**Now here is the weird part.**

If I *start* by turning off my wifi, open a python terminal, and call socket.getaddrinfo, as expected I will receive the same error as before

```
In [2]: socket.getaddrinfo('charlesleifer.com', 80)
---------------------------------------------------------
gaierror                                  Traceback (most
<ipython-input-2-d333ec6c75af> in <module>()
----> 1 socket.getaddrinfo('charlesleifer.com', 80)

gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

But when I turn my wifi on, no matter how many times I try I will continue to receive this same error! I can try other hosts and it will also fail.

If I manually add an entry to my `/etc/hosts` file, then it will return whatever I put in the hosts file. Other requests continue to fail, though.

What's going on here?  I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine shared the following patch, which manually flushes the resolver cache. This fixed the issue for me.

http://bugs.sugarlabs.org/attachment/ticket/1940/network.py.patch